# Java: useDelimiter to get rid of capital lettered words?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I am trying to use Scanner's "useDelimiter" method to check a .txt file and add the words to a String[] array, no punctuation, capital lettered words, spaces, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your regex, instead use:

```
[ ',!?.;:()`-]+
```

notice `-` is now at the end. Your old regex was checking for following characters -  `',!?.;:(` and for characters in range between `)` and "tilde". This range included capital letters.

Comment: This fixed my problem perfectly. Thank you so much!